# Give the output after ./a.out quotes.txt, where quotes.txt?

Tags: c

I need to be led in the correct direction.  I was given a program to clean up and then have the C program run and read a txt file. I do not  have any info on how to have a c program read to/from an external text file to produce a new output. The question, code and quotes.txt file are below.

---

Give the output after `./a.out quotes.txt`

quotes.txt:

```
Controlling complexity
is the essence of computer programming.
First, solve the problem. Then, write the code.
Code is like humor. When you have to explain it, it’s bad.
Any fool can write code that a computer can understand.
Good programmers write code that humans can understand.
Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code
will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.
Good code is its own best documentation.
As you're about to add a comment, ask yourself, "How can I improve 
the code so that this comment isn't needed?"
Improve the code and then document it to make it even clearer.
Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
A good programmer is someone who always looks both ways 
before crossing a one-way street.
Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible,
you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.
```

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/**
 * Traces the first uppercase letter of each line in the given file.
 * Stops after finding 9 uppercase letters.
 * 
 * @param filename The name of the file to trace.
 * @return 0 on success.
 */

int tracel(char *filename) 
{
    FILE *fin = fopen(filename, "r");
    int count = 0;
    char data[128];

    while (fgets(data, 120, fin)) 
    {
        if (isupper(data[0])) 
            {
                printf("%c", data[0]);
                count++;
            }
                if (9 == count)
                     break;
    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Traces the first uppercase letter of each word in the given file.
 * Stops after finding 9 uppercase letters.
 * 
 * @param filename The name of the file to trace.
 * @return 0 on success.
 */
int trace2(char *filename) 
{
   FILE *fin = fopen(filename, "r");
    int count = 0;
    char data[128];

    while (1 == fscanf(fin, "%s", data)) 
    {
        if (isupper(data[0])) 
        {
            printf("%c", data[0]);
            count++;
        }
            if (9 == count)
            break;
    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    if (argc > 1) 
    {
        printf("Tracel\n");
        tracel(argv[1]);
        printf("Trace2\n");
        trace2(argv[1]);
    } 
        else 
        {
            printf("That was easy!\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

I created the `quotes.txt` file but at that point, I have no knowledge of how to get the C program to point to it and run

Comment: `argv[1]` is the first command line argument to the program. You can see where it is used in the code you've shown which opens and reads the file.

Comment: If the quotes.txt is not in the current directory then you will have to specify a path.  Other than that it actually works: https://onlinegdb.com/V0bwsq4tl

Comment: Check return value from all i/o operations otherwise you are wasting time.

Comment: The simplest way is putting `a.out` and `quotes.txt` at the same folder.

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  Yes, in hindsight it was quite simple to match up the source code and txt file into the same folder. I then used a.exe_quotes.txt via the terminal after running the program and creating the executable.